# Как обращаться к контроллеру WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Имеется метод действия в контроллере:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(string email)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);

            if (result.Succeeded)
                return Ok();
            else
                return BadRequest();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Как обратиться к нему из моего приложения?

Comment: В зависимости от настроек роутера. Скорее всего такой будет:
www.site.com/api/conrollerName/delete

Answer (score 0):

Если метод в Api Get можешь написать такой запрос, который в свою очередь тебе возвратит результат в твоем случае это статус код:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/api/Delete?email=example@ex.com");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var getResponseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Если Post запрос:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/api/Delete");

var emailDataString = "email=example@ex.com";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(emailDataString);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```